# How to write erro or exception into log file that named with date?

Tags: java

I have written a code. But I found everytime it written the error into log file, it will totally cover  the existed file, not to appended after it. What happened...

```
try {
            int s = 1 / 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                Date d = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
                String s = sdf.format(d);
                String day = sd.format(d);

                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("src/log/"+day+"_Exception.log");
                ps.println(s);

                System.setErr(ps);
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
```

Comment: Read the javadocs *file - The file to use as the destination of this print stream. If the file exists, then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.*

Comment: `PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("src/log/"+day+"_Exception.log", true);` will allow  to append in existing file.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Thanks for comment...but it still didn't work... IDEA reported "Cannot resolve constructor 'PrintStream(java.lang.String, boolean)'". By the way this is using JDK8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a new `PrintStream` with a `String` argument is created, the argument is interpreted as the path of a new `FileOutputStream` to create.

So the sentence:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("src/log/"+day+"_Exception.log");
```

bsically creates a new `FileOutputStream` with the default "append" flag, that is `false`.

To realize the append that you want, you have to modify your code as follow:

```
try {
    int s = 1 / 0;
} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
        String s = sdf.format(d);
        String day = sd.format(d);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("src/log/" + day + "_Exception.log");
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);

        ps.println(s);

        System.setErr(ps);
    } catch (Exception e2) {
    }
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you Andrea Annibali!! It works!!